# An error occurred. The operation couldn’t be completed. (ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain error 401.)

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I am not getting to work the Validation build option in iTunes connect please help.
I uploaded sucessfully, but I didn't get the archive validated.

Comment: I have the same issue when trying to Validate an App to App Store from XCode Archives. I was able to "Upload" the ipa successfully. This error appeared only when "Validating" the App (a step I usually do before hand).